# losetup: How to use the -f option?

Tags: loop-device

For example, I would like to setup `mydata.img` to `/dev/loop5`, I would expect using the command below. However it gives the error **losetp: unexpected arguments.**

```
losetup --show -Pvf /dev/loop5 mydata.img
```

(-v is optional, just for more verbose output. -P is not a main concern in this question too. It forces partition scan. --show is also optional. It shows the assigned loop device.)

In particular, the simpler command below gives the same **losetp: unexpected arguments** error.

```
losetup -f /dev/loop5 mydata.img
```

I think I am following the syntax below. But why `-f` does not setup `mydata.img` to `/dev/loop5`? I know `losetup -f` will find the first unused loop device. But is it possible to assign another `loopdev` instead of the first unused found? In particular, there is a `loopdev` argument in the syntax below. How should we interpret it?

[man losetup](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/losetup.8.html)

> Set up a loop device:
>
> ```
>    losetup [-o offset] [--sizelimit size] [--sector-size size] [-Pr]
>    [--show] -f loopdev file
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> -f, --find [file]
>        Find the first unused loop device. If a file argument is
>        present, use the found device as loop device. Otherwise, just
>        print its name.
> ```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to select which loop device will be used, you need to use this syntax

```
losetup /dev/loopX mydata.img
```

The man page is a little bit confusing, but technically correct, because it shows

```
losetup ... [-Pr] [--show] -f|loopdev file
```

and if you check what `|` means in [man man](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) it says:

```
options delimited by | cannot be used together.
```

so you can use either `losetup -f` (optionally with `file` argument) or `losetup <loopdev> <file>`. So `-f` in the command replaces the loop device positional argument in this case.

Edit: As pointed in the comments, the `|` was lost between util-linux 2.36 and the latest 2.37 so now the man page is not correct.

Comment: "The man page is a little bit confusing, but technically correct" – Well, the man page in Debian or so is technically correct. The online man page the OP links to is exactly as the OP cites, `-f loopdev` is there. This particular manual seems *wrong*.

Comment: The pipe was lost when the `losetup` manual page was converted to Asciidoc.

Comment: Thanks, I checked only my local `losetup` manpage and I'm still on 2.36. I've created a [PR for util-linux](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/pull/1556) to add the pipe back.

Comment: Heh, I didn’t realise that GH PRs were accepted, I submitted [a patch too](https://lore.kernel.org/util-linux/20220106104806.hgqz5hcddmqb5ak4@ws.net.home/T/) ;-). Yours is merged now, so the problem is fixed!